# Proof that coherent states are eigenstates of annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator, eigenvalue, coherent-states

> My goal is to prove that, for $|\lambda\rangle=N\exp(\lambda\hat{a}^\dagger)|0\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the operator $\hat a$.

I took 2 approaches, but both make sense to me and I get different results, and I can't find the loophole:

**1st attempt** 
From the commutation relation $[\hat a, \hat{a}^\dagger]=\hat1$ we can generalize to:

$$
[\hat a, (\hat{a}^\dagger)^2]=\hat1 \hat{a}^\dagger+\hat{a}^\dagger\hat 1=2\hat{a}^\dagger  \\ 
[\hat a, (\hat{a}^\dagger)^3]=2(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2+(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2 2=4(\hat{a}^\dagger)^2\\
[\hat a, (\hat{a}^\dagger)^4]=4(\hat{a}^\dagger)^3+(\hat{a}^\dagger)^34=8(\hat{a}^\dagger)^3\\
\vdots \\
[\hat a, (\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n+1}]=(2\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n},\hspace{10px} n=0,1,2,\dots
$$

we then have that $\hat a (\hat a^\dagger)^{n+1}=(2\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}+ (\hat a^\dagger)^{n+1}\hat a$, hence:

$$
\hat a|\lambda\rangle=N\hat a\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n (\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n \hat a(\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\bigg(\hat a|0\rangle+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^n \hat a(\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \bigg) \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^n (2\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}+ (\hat a^\dagger)^{n+1}\hat a}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^n (2\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\lambda\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n (2\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\lambda\exp(2\lambda\hat{a}^\dagger)|0\rangle
=N\lambda |2\lambda\rangle
$$

Clearly this does not prove anything...

**2nd attempt**
$$
\hat a|\lambda\rangle=N\hat a\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n (\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=N\hat a\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n \sqrt{n!}}{n!}|n\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n \hat a}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n \sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n-1\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\lambda^n}{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}|n-1\rangle \\
=N\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle \\
=N\lambda \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle \\
=N\lambda\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\lambda^n (\hat{a}^\dagger)^{n}}{n!}|0\rangle \\
=\lambda|\lambda\rangle
$$

and with this I get the correct result. Where is the loophole?

Comment: I think it's your commutation relations - for power n it should be $n a^\dagger$ no?

Comment: I'm sorry, they were poorly written, it's corrected now. But even so, I don't think it is $na^\dagger$ since those all of those steps are defined recursively, yielding that relation.

Comment: I voted to close because this is a [check-my-work problem](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is in your commutator. It's instructive to show that for two operators $A$ and $B$ which commute with their commutator, i.e. $[[A,B],B] = 0$, we have $$[A, B^n] = n B^{n-1} [A,B].$$

(Actually, a more general relation is that in this case $[A, f(B)]= f'(B) [A,B].$)

From this, the rest of your proof is pretty straightforward.

**Proof of commutator identity:**

You can actually show the first quite simply using induction. Clearly, it is true for $n=1$. Now assume it is true for $n=k$, i.e. assume that $$[A,B^k] = k B^{k-1} [A,B].$$ Let's try to show it for $[A, B^{k+1}]$

\begin{eqnarray}
[A, B^{k+1}] &=& [A,B^k] B + B^k[A,B] \\
             &=& k B^{k-1}[A,B] B + B^k [A,B]\\
             &=& (k+1)B^k [A,B],
\end{eqnarray}

where in the last step I've just used that $[A,B]$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: I'd appreciate a reason for the down-vote, in case I can do anything to improve my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use the relation
$$
\exp(-\lambda a^\dagger)a\exp(\lambda a^\dagger)=a+\lambda.
$$